# Saving file to AWS S3 via AWS lambda with boto3 is not saving the correct file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, boto3

Currently I am developing an API that allows users to upload files to their cloud storages (which is on my platform). The Cloud storage is on AWS S3, and the file saving function is using AWS Lambda Python & developed using AWS Chalice.

However, when the chalice application was hosted locally on my computer by using the command `chalice local`, everything was file, the files were saved to S3 in the correct format. Once deployed to AWS Lambda, the files are still being saved to s3 successfully, but the formats are just wrong. which means when you download the uploaded files, they would not work at all.

my code is as below:

```
"""
    upload data to the target path
"""
@app.route('/upload', methods=["PUT"], content_types=['application/json'])
def upload():

    try:
        user_id   = app.current_request.headers["use_user_id"]
        file_path = app.current_request.headers["use_data_path"]

        target_path = os.path.join("aiii-"+user_id, "data", file_path)
        file = app.current_request.raw_body

        return savingObjectToBucket(target_path, file)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
```

the file saving function:

```
def savingObjectToBucket(fileName:str, body):

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.Object("aiii-big-fat-bucket", fileName).put(Body=body)
    print("Object successfully saved to bucket.")
    return True
```

Would anybody give me a kind help?

Thanks in advance! Appreciate it!

Comment: How did you configure the `API Gateway`?

Comment: What do you mean by wrong format? Is the content right, just not encoded the way you expect it (e.g. JSON/raw data)?

Comment: @MaiKaY The API Gateway was automatically configured by Chalice, calling the Lambda function was no problem

Comment: @KimBurgaard So the whole data saving process was successful, but when Lambda saves the file into S3, the file size increases, and when retrieved for use, the files are just not right (PDFs are blank, images can not be opened, etc).